# implode an array value

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I've a multi-select attribute color.

```
$color = $_product->getAttributeText('color');
$output = implode(',', $color);
echo $output;
```

$color gives an array value. If there are multiple values present for the color attribute, say 1. blue and 2. green, it prints blue,green but when only one attribute is present for $color (say blue), it doesn't print any thing.

Is that the normal behaviour of implode? There must be multiple values present in array? If not then how I can print those single present values?

Comment: No, this is not the normal behaviour of `implode()`. What is the output of: `print_r($color);` when you only receive one value ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `is_array()`.

```
$color = $_product->getAttributeText('color');

if (is_array($color)) {
  $output = implode(',', $color);
} else {
  $output = $color;
}

echo $output;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to go out on a limb here, but I am going to guess that if there is one value returned it's a string; a string is invalid input for `implode` and will raise a `PHP Warning`.

In this case, `implode` will return a `null` value, which would explain why you are seeing nothing printed.

So ensure that you are passing an array to `implode` in all cases.

**Edit**

If you cannot see debug information in your *development* environment then you should consider setting your `error_reporting()` to help you debug your code. One simple way to do this is to add the following lines to the top of your script:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

// your code...
```

Note that you should not enable these settings in a production environment for security reasons.

Comment: Yes the value returned is a string. That makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Hello Dear,


    $color = 'blue';
    $output = implode(',', $color);
    echo $output;

It will give you a warning.

Warning: Invalid arguments passed.

But it works fine with array

    $color = array('blue');
    $output = implode(',', $color);
    echo $output;

Check the return value stored in `$color` and then go ahead.
Thanks.
```